# is there any way to calculate height of irregular tetrahedron with pythagoras theorem

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

given an irregular tetrahedron of side length $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$,$f$, is it possible to find the perpendicular distance from its apex to base with the help of pythagoras theorem

Comment: Yes $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \           $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using two expressions for the volume of the tetrahedron $ABCD$
\begin{align}
V&=\tfrac13\,S_{abc}\cdot h
,\\
V&=
\frac1{12}\,
\left(
4\, u^2\, v^2\, w^2+(u^2+v^2-c^2)\, (v^2+w^2-a^2)\, (u^2+w^2-b^2)
\right.
\\
&\phantom{=}
\left.
-u^2\, (v^2+w^2-a^2)^2-v^2\, (u^2+w^2-b^2)^2-w^2\, (u^2+v^2-c^2)^2
\right)^{1/2}
,
\end{align}

where

\begin{align} 
a&=|BC|
,\quad 
b=|AC|
,\quad 
c=|AB|
,\\ 
u&=|AD|
,\quad 
v=|BD|
,\quad 
w=|CD|
.
\end{align}

See
[The volume of the pyramid in terms of its side lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Heron-type_formula_for_the_volume_of_a_tetrahedron)
for the reference.